# How to include selfLink and navigationLink in ASP.NET Web API 2 OData v4 responses?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata, hypermedia

I would like to include the selfLink and navigationLink(s) in my JSON responses like this:

```
{
    "@odata.count": 4,
    "@odata.nextLink": http://example.com/v1.0/Entity?$top=2&$skip=2",
    "value": [
    {
      "@odata.selfLink": http://example.com/v1.0/Entity(610375)",
      "id": 610375,
      "description": "ABCDE",         
      "OtherEntities@odata.navigationLink": "http://example.com/v1.0/Entity(610375)/OtherEntities"
    },
    {
        "@odata.selfLink": "http://example.com/v1.0/Entity(602762)",
        "id": 602762,
        "description": "KLMNOP",
        "OtherEntities@odata.navigationLink": "http://example.com/v1.0/Entity(602762)/OtherEntities",
   }
}
```

I noticed the existence of methods like:

- builder.EntitySet("Entities").HasFeedSelfLink(...)
- LinkGenerationHelpers.GenerateSelfLink(..)

But I have no idea on how to use them or even if I should use this?

**Update:**
I found out that it is possible to add *Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=full* in the HTTP header. This will give me @odata.navigationLink, @odata.id (what I meant with selfLink) and a whole bunch of other @odata metadata. This leads me to two new questions though:

1. Is it possible to change the default to odata-metadata=full serverside?
2. Is it possible to add a custom metadata format that allows me to only output some of these @odata metadata and if possible change the name of some of them?

Comment: Have you ever found out whether it is possible to configure the API to return the full metadata by default?

Comment: No sorry...just used the HTTP header method and moved on to the next project.